# Is it possible to install different versions of binaries in Hyperledger Fabric at the same time?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am trying out samples in Hyperledger Fabric and installed the binaries for version 1.4 using the "curl" command by adding "-s 1.4.0"

```
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.4.0
```

This installs all the required binaries (cryptogen,configtxgen etc.. ).

Is it possible to install a set of binaries for a different version at the same time in the same machine (using command `$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh| bash -s 1.1.0`) 
If this is possible i could switch between two versions 1.1 and 1.4 for testing out the byfn network and the binaries wouldnt collide. Is it even possible or is there a way to do this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use multiple version with a couple of modification.

Rename the `bin` folder as `bin11` for `v1.1`.

Make a copy of `byfn.sh` file and rename it as `byfn11.sh`.
Update the `bin` folder path to the `bin11` in the `byfn11.sh`.
Export the Image version to `1.1` before using the `byfn11.sh`, else it will use the latest fabric images.

you can make the above process simple by updating the `bin` path in `byfn` as variable. Like whenever the `ImageVersion` is `1.1` use `bin11` else `bin`.

> Use the above process with precaution, if you mix the image version and bin version then you might get some errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure.

Use

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.4.0
```

to download 1.4.0 binaries in the folder you are right now.
Next take the bin folder and move it somewhere else or just rename the folder in **bin140**.

Next use

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0
```

And download 1.1.0 binaries. Do the same now for folder **bin110**.

Now you just need to change the blockchain script you are running, I don't know if it byfn.sh or a different one, but you can indicate the correct folder where to pick your binaries or use an environment variable to do so.